# For every first li in ul, do this

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul:not(.sub-menu) {
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

ul li:first-child:not(.sub-menu) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.submenu {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>has submenu
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>child</li>
      <li>child</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the `li`'s which doesn't have a nested `ul` to have a `margin-bottom` of `30px`. But with my current approach, it adds a margin to the nested `ul li` elements too.

I almost need to do `ul li:first-child:not(.sub-menu li)` but that's not possible. What's the workaround?

Comment: Why don't you just give your first ul a class `first-ul` and style them like `ul.first-ul li { margin: 10px }`?

Comment: You want to select `li` based on children so that would require https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has which currently is not supported in css.

Comment: @ritaj your answer still will select all `li` elements, you will need to change it to `ul.first-ul > li`

Comment: To be more specific selector would look something like this `li:not(:has(> ul.submenu))` but this would also select nested li's so then you need to select based on parent `ul:not(.submenu) li:not(:has(> ul.submenu))`

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you can't edit the html and don't need it to be dynamic

```
ul > li:not(:nth-of-type(4)){
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I've selected all direct child `li` elements of the parent `ul`, except the 4th

**OR**

If you need it to be dynamic you can use jQuery

```
$('ul li').each(function(){ // cycle through each li

    if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('submenu')){ // check if parent doesn't have class 'submenu'

        $(this).css('padding-bottom','30px'); // if not, add padding
    }

})
```

Comment: Tried it on js fiddle, does not work. see: https://jsfiddle.net/0w4ygqjf/

Comment: I've just edited my answer